# In AutoIt for Windows 7, how do I only run the script if there is no user interaction for a period of time?

Tags: windows, scripting, autoit

I'm trying to make a script that, if the user is not performing any action (keyboard or mouse) for a set period of time, the window focus switches.

Comment: Does mouse action include moving the mouse? And where should the window focus switch to? To the next inactive window like pressing **Alt+Tab**? Our just focus the next control inside the window like pressing **Tab**?

Answer (score 0):

This script will activate notepad when the user has been idle for 30 seconds:

```
#include <Timers.au3>

while (true)
    $idleTime = _Timer_GetIdleTime()

    if $idleTime > 30000 and not WinActive("Untitled - Notepad") Then
        WinActivate("Untitled - Notepad")
    EndIf

    Sleep(1000)
WEnd
```